# How do I represent subflows in Python Luigi task manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, luigi

Suppose I have flow A->B.  Users of this flow require B.  Suppose I have a task C which requires B but I want D to happen before flow A->B.  How do I do this in [Luigi](http://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to pass C's requirements into subflow A->B:

```
import luigi

class A(luigi.Task):
  precedes = luigi.Parameter()

  def requires(self):
     return self.precedes

class B(luigi.Task):
  precedes = luigi.Parameter()

  def requires(self):
     return A(precedes = self.precedes)

class D(luigi.Task):
  pass

class C(luigi.Task):
  def requires(self):
      return B(precedes = D())
```